# Create folder when folder name is in a cell in the sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following macro to create a folder:

```
Sub Create_Folder1()
If Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Sheet1.Range("A1"), vbDirectory) = "test" Then
  MsgBox "Folder already exists!"
Else
    MkDir ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Sheet1.Range("A1")
End If
End Sub
```

I want to write the folder name in cell A1 in the Excel sheet. However, when I run this code I get runtime error 75.

Do you have any idea where the mistake is in my code?

Comment: try the code in my answer below (you need to save the workbook with this code inside first)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code (don't forget to save `ThisWorkbook` first, otherwise you will get an error message).

```
Sub Create_Folder1()

If Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Sheet1.Range("A1"), vbDirectory) = "test" Then
    MsgBox "Folder already exists!"
Else
    MkDir Application.ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Sheet1.Range("A1")
End If

End Sub
```